Nestjs Discriminators
I have a Discount Model that has a dynamic property type which can be one of three Models (Vegetable or Bread or Beer), after taking a look at Nest’s official documentation, I believe that by using discriminators I can achieve that.

Note: I have also another Model (Item) that also uses the same process

I am encountering this error after running the server
[Nest] 9181  - 04/22/2024, 3:21:24 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot overwrite `Beer` model once compiled.
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Beer` model once compiled.
    at Function.Model.discriminator (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/mongoose@8.3.2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1244:11)
    at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+mongoose@10.0.6_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+core@10.3.8_mongoose@8.3.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose.providers.js:10:42)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.8_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.8_reflect-metadata@0.2.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:368:55)
    at callback (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.8_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.8_reflect-metadata@0.2.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:65:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.8_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.8_reflect-metadata@0.2.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:144:24)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.8_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.8_reflect-metadata@0.2.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:70:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.8_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.8_reflect-metadata@0.2.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:97:9)
    at /Users/lablabeedev/code/online-grocery-store/node_modules/.pnpm/@nestjs+core@10.3.8_@nestjs+common@10.3.8_@nestjs+platform-express@10.3.8_reflect-metadata@0.2.2_rxjs@7.8.1/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:56:13
    at async Promise.all (index 3)

The Discount module looks like this
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Beer, BeerSchema } from '../beer/schemas/beer.schema';
import { Bread, BreadSchema } from '../bread/schemas/bread.schema';
import {
  Vegetable,
  VegetableSchema,
} from '../vegetable/schemas/vegetable.schema';
import { DiscountController } from './discount.controller';
import { DiscountService } from './discount.service';
import { Discount, DiscountSchema } from './schemas/discount.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Discount.name,
        schema: DiscountSchema,
        discriminators: [
          { name: Beer.name, schema: BeerSchema },
          { name: Vegetable.name, schema: VegetableSchema },
          { name: Bread.name, schema: BreadSchema },
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [DiscountController],
  providers: [DiscountService],
})
export class DiscountModule {}

And the Discount schema looks like this (I specified the discriminatorKey following the documentation)
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Beer } from '../../beer/schemas/beer.schema';
import { Bread } from '../../bread/schemas/bread.schema';
import { Vegetable } from '../../vegetable/schemas/vegetable.schema';

// export enum DiscountType {
//   Vegetable = 'Vegetable',
//   Beer = 'Beer',
//   Bread = 'Bread',
// }
export type ItemType = Vegetable | Beer | Bread;
export type DiscountDocument = Discount & Document;

@Schema({ discriminatorKey: 'type' })
export class Discount {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: '1',
    description: 'The unique identifier for the discount',
  })
  @Prop()
  id: string;

  @Prop({
    type: { type: String },
    enum: ['Vegetable', 'Beer', 'Bread'],
  })
  type: ItemType;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 3.99,
    description: 'The price of the discount',
  })
  @Prop({ required: true })
  price: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 1,
    description: 'The age of the discount in days',
  })
  @Prop({ required: true })
  ageInDays: number;
}

export const DiscountSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Discount);

